# Angular wait for response with rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

How can I write a function to wait for the return value using rxjs? I want to show the confirm dialog only if MyString is not empty

My code is as below

```
private showConfirmation(): boolean{
    let confirmResponse = false;
    if( this.MyString!== '' ) {
        this.alertService.confirm( 'Confirm', this.MyString + 'Are you sure you want to proceed?' ).pipe(
            take(1),
            filter( confirm =>  !!confirm),
            tap(value => {
                confirmResponse = true;
            }),
        ).subscribe();
    }
    return confirmResponse;
}
```

Comment: You should probably be returning an `Observable<boolean>` not using `tap` and subscribe to that upstream but that depends on what's calling this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking about it wrong. You should be treating your data as a stream that is consumed higher up. It's hard to be explicit and I would recommend you read [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular). But I would probably change your code to:

```js
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { take, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


private showConfirmation(): Observable<boolean>{

    if( this.MyString!== '' ) {
        return this.alertService.confirm( 'Confirm', this.MyString + 'Are you sure you want to proceed?' ).pipe(
            take(1),
            switchMap( confirm =>  !!confirm)
        );
    }
    return of(false);
}
```

and then whatever is calling this should subscribe to it, possibly using the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe):

```html
<p>{{showConfirmation() | async}}</p>
```